# menuitem and contextmenu crossbrowser compatibility

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-browser, contextmenu, menuitem

Problem 1: I had made my own `contextmenu` using the following piece of code.

```
function addFullScreenMenu () {
var menu = document.createElement('menu');
var item = document.createElement('menuitem');
menu.setAttribute('id', 'fsmenu');
menu.setAttribute('type', 'context');
item.setAttribute('label', 'Fullscreen');
item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
if (window.fullScreen) {
document.body.mozCancelFullScreen();
} else {
document.body.mozRequestFullScreen();
}
});
menu.appendChild(item);
document.body.appendChild(menu);
document.body.setAttribute('contextmenu', 'fsmenu');
}
```

Issue: Works in Firefox but fails in  Google Chrome (Version 21.0.1180.81).

What corrections should be done so that it does not fail in Google Chrome?

---

Problem 2: Capturing right click event using `EventListener`

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
            alert("You've tried to open context menu"); //gets alerted in firefox and googlechrome
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
    } else {
        document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
            alert("You've tried to open context menu");//gets alerted in Internet explorer
            window.event.returnValue = false;
        });
    }
</script>
```

Issue: EventListener for right click not working in Internet Explorer(Version 9)

**Update**: I can solve problem2 form Phx answer . Need solution for problem1.

Comment: Internet Explorer has many versions, can you post exactly wich versions are you using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bMW4k/1/ and it's running right click. Can your check this

Comment: Yeah I checked it.Its working over there.

Comment: So your code it's working on IE 9. Can you check console log for javascript errors? as i see in your code you have two ** in this line. alert("You've tried to open context menu");**// this will throw a error.

Comment: ** are not present in actual code.They came over when I tried to bold the text

Comment: not related to the question, but google chrome version 21? on may 9 2014? That's old.

Comment: @guest I had tested in latest chrome also

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer (**up to version 8**) used an alternate `attachEvent` method.

**Internet Explorer 9** supports the proper `addEventListener` method.

```
if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
      elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
   }
```

Check this link. 
[addEventListener in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927637/addeventlistener-in-internet-explorer)

And another important link:

> You shouldn't be using DOM 0 events (events attached via HTML
>   attributes). You should use event listeners, attached using
>   element.addEventListener in W3C browsers and element.attachEvent in
>   IE. If you're building a large website, you should be using a JS
>   framework, but that's a different question that you didn't ask. A
>   framework (the most popular being jQuery) would provide abstract
>   methods to do this, but in the absence of one, here's a simple
>   function to do it cross-browser.

[Event handler not working in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112431/event-handler-not-working-in-internet-explorer)

This is a jsFiddle that i have build with your code. It's works with IE 9 (and it's the same code)

http://jsfiddle.net/bMW4k/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are using Mozilla-specific functions, namely `.mozRequestFullScreen();` and `.mozCancelFullScreen();`.

The fullscreen API isn't fully implemented yet in many web browsers. If you want to use it, I recommend using a polyfill. Here's a good one: https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/. (It's actually a wrapper, but it will do the job.)

With the polyfill included, your code would look like:

```
function addFullScreenMenu () {
    var menu = document.createElement('menu');
    var item = document.createElement('menuitem');
    menu.setAttribute('id', 'fsmenu');
    menu.setAttribute('type', 'context');
    item.setAttribute('label', 'Fullscreen');
    item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (screenfull.enabled) {
                screenfull.toggle(this);
        }
        else {
            alert("This browser doesn't support Fullscreen API.");
        }
    });
    menu.appendChild(item);
    document.body.appendChild(menu);
    document.body.setAttribute('contextmenu', 'fsmenu');
}
```

Comment: I had changed the full screen menu item and tried something different which didn't work at all